# How to migrate GCP OAuth client ID's to another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have two different projects in **GCP**. I want to migrate the **OAuth 2.0** Client ID's from one project to another. Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to migrate client id's they are linked to the project that created them you will need to create new clients over on the other project.

I am curious to know why you would need them moved to a different project.

Comment: I want to delete one project which has the client ids and use the other one.

Comment: that would delete the clients.  You cant move them.

Comment: Regarding "Moving to different project": Wouldn't making a new client id under a new project mean, say, all users who did Google Sign In will no longer be able to Sign In again since their google id is tied to the old (now deleted) client id.

Comment: Yes users would need to authorize to the new client.